# Phrase 'too far from'

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-usage

As far as I know, the phrase 'too far from' could be used with

- noun (too far from a good car - *bad car*)
- adjective (too far from beautiful - *it isn't beautiful*)
- adverb (too far from always - *rarely*)

QUESTION:

Can I use this way of using the phrase 'too far from'?

> man A: no one can do this exercise
>
> man B: It's **too far from no one can do it**

Comment: I don't know where you got the idea of using ***too far from***, but none of your examples are idiomatic. The metaphoric usage *Explaining this is far from easy* is perfectly natural, but I think ***too*** would rarely if ever be used like that. I can only imagine it in *literal* contexts such as *I live **too far from the town** to walk there, so I rely on the bus.*

Comment: Also note that even without that clumsy ***too***, the specific constructions *far from always* and *far from good* simply aren't used (but [*far from beautiful*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22far+from+beautiful%22) is common enough).

Comment: @FumbleFingers The first example that I recall is from the movie 'Pulp fiction' _(too far from 'okay')_

Comment: @FumbleFingers [**far from everyone** on Independence Square likes her](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2014/feb/22/ukraine-tymoshenko-president-protests)

Comment: @FumbleFingers [**still far from being granted** the priority status that it deserves](http://www.europarl.europa.eu/sides/getDoc.do?pubRef=-//EP//TEXT+CRE+20010906+ITEMS+DOC+XML+V0//EN&amp;language=EN)

Comment: Correction to idiom: something is far from being something. Not "too far from". So then: This is far from being something that no one can do. Now, it works.

Comment: @Max: Oh, *that* one! But it's just a ridiculously stylised reply from Marsellus. He's just been brutally ass-raped, so he doesn't think much of Butch asking ***You okay?*** *(No, I'm fuckin' **not** okay!)*. But that's not what I was talking about. I'm saying you're mistaken in thinking you can extend this metaphoric usage willy-nilly into ***too** far from [whatever something is emphatically **not**])*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*From X* won't work if X is a new clause with a subject and verb.

A gerund or participle is needed, or you can use a relative pronoun that makes sense.

The gerund or participle form of *can* is "being able to."

So:

> It's too far from no one being able to do it.

or

> It's too far from where no one could do it.

Also, your example is confusing, it seems like B is agreeing with A, in that no one can do the exercise.  So B should not use a negative expression as it sounds like B doesn't agree with A otherwise.

> man A: no one can do this exercise
>
> man B: It's too far from *anyone being able to do it* or *It's too far from where anyone could do it.*.

Comment: I disagree with your first two examples. They are not idiomatic in  my book. it's far from anyone being able to do it. One wouldn't say ***too far from*** here.

Comment: I agree with Lambie. Not only are they not idiomatic, but I think the negative is outright ungrammatical.

Answer (score 2):

When speaking casually, we do say things like

> I too far from sober to drive.

or

> She's too far from satisfied with that paint job to recommend those painters to anybody

by analogy with

> This apartment is too far from work to be a good place to live.

But I can't think of any examples with an adverb or a predicate.